# Экземпляры Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Сколько экземпляров можно создать?

```
new Vue({
    el: "#example",
    data: {}
})
```

Или надо только один корневой?
По документации не совсем понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В 99.9% случаев вам не понадобится создавать более 1 инстанса Vue

Всё остальное реализуется с помощью компонентов https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Создаете `<div id="app"> //your content </div>` и с помощью шаблонизаторов все страницы наследуете от главного шаблона.

Answer (score 2):

Если нет цели строить страницу на основе компонентов, то можно создавать сколько угодно, если это какие-то несвязанные вещи. Но нужен ли в таком случае сам vue?..